# Error when importing the LinkedIn API in Python

Tags: python, linkedin-api

I'm currently trying to use the LinkedIn API with Python on Spyder, but just importing the module provokes an error:

```
from linkedin import linkedin
```

Error:

> runfile('SOME_PATH/LinkedIn/main.py', wdir='SOME_PATH/LinkedIn')
>   UMD has deleted: credentials
>
> File "SOME_PATH\linkedin.py", line 294
>       except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError), error:
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Are you using python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[That library](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/)¹ apparently only works on python 2.

```
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError), error:
```

is python 2 syntax. It is invalid syntax in python 3.

¹ I'm assuming it is that library because there are bug reports with exactly the same error on the same line.

Related issues:

- https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/issues/70 "Syntax Error"
- https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/issues/77 "Python 3 support"

Answer (score 6):

Use the following code in command window:

```
pip install --upgrade https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/tarball/master
```

Comment: This got me upgraded to python 3, but now i'm getting "This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs"  I wonder if you know of a new library that works for Linked v2 APIs?